Unexpected argument --relay-chain found
I am following the parachain-template readme.md. I am trying to generate chain_spec.json file using the following command
chain-spec-builder create --relay-chain "rococo-local" --para-id 1000 --runtime \
    target/release/wbuild/parachain-template-runtime/parachain_template_runtime.wasm named-preset development

It gives me an error as follows
error: unexpected argument '--relay-chain' found

Usage: chain-spec-builder create [OPTIONS] --runtime-wasm-path <RUNTIME_WASM_PATH> <COMMAND>

For more information, try '--help'.

I followed all the instructions still i am getting an error.

There isn't --relay-chain in this version.

https://crates.io/crates/staging-chain-spec-builder/versions?sort=date
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blame/87971b3e92721bdf10bf40b410eaae779d494ca0/substrate/bin/utils/chain-spec-builder/src/lib.rs#L151-L173

The README you are reading is on polkadot-stable2412-rc2.
The crates.io is on polkadot-stable2409.

If you want to use the latest README.
Install the crate from git source.
cargo install staging-chain-spec-builder --git  https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk


If you want to install from crates.io, checkout the README to polkadot-stable2409 tag.

Thanks. I installed the crate from git source and now it works
